# Combine: resetting observed boolean within sink() call?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have the following code:

```
    $myBoolean
        .debounce(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .removeDuplicates()
        .sink { newValue in
            self.myBoolean = false
            ....... 
            ...... (closure called every 2 seconds if I don't use `removeDuplicates()`)
        }
        .store(in: &subscribers)
```

I am using sink() on a @Published var in my observable object. Different parts of the app can set that boolean to `true`. When that happens, I want the code in `sink()` to run.

When that happens I want the code to reset `myBoolean` to false. So, only when I know the sink() code runs I want the boolean to be set back to false.

How can I set myBoolean back to false only when the sink() code runs without cause endless calls to the sink()?

`myBoolean` is declared like so:

```
@Published fileprivate var myBoolean:Bool = false
```

Comment: you could try: `if !newValue { return }` at the start of your sink. And `removeDuplicates` should have worked too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Custom type `MyBool` and `filter` operator you can get similar behaviour.

```
import Combine

class Abc: ObservableObject {
    struct MyBool: Equatable {
        let value: Bool
        let isFromSinkCall: Bool
    }
    
    @Published var myBoolean: MyBool = .init(value: true, isFromSinkCall: false)
    
    private var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        $myBoolean
            .debounce(for: 2, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
            .filter({ !$0.isFromSinkCall })
            .sink { newValue in
                self.myBoolean = .init(value: false, isFromSinkCall: true)
            }
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }
}
```